# What's the situation with XSLT and XPATH in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, xslt, xpath

I'm writing javascript code to traverse and manipulate deeply nested XML documents. With modern browsers, is there still a need for crossbrowser libraries like:

- [sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/)
- [ajaxslt](http://goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net/)

As far as I know, without using one of these there won't be any XPath in IE with ActiveX disabled. And a simple wrapper is needed for both XSLT and XPath to distinguish between IE and w3c XML Dom.

Comment: Are you including IE6 in `modern browsers`?

Comment: No, Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, Opera 10, Google Chrome. Also see the list in goog-ajaxslt.sourceforge.net/README for some browsers from 2008.

Comment: do you have to do the XML manipulation locally? 

we have tended to avoid and do any XSLT/XPath stuff server side (using datapower hardware) which has performance benefits as well as removing the worry about the local browser. Well, at least reducing it to a HTML/Javascript worry.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, since I'm writing a web based editor for XML files I'd really like to do as much XML in the browser as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you stick to XSLT 1.0 functionality, I would say that XSL and XPATH support work reasonably well on all browsers, even as far back as IE6.

That being said, there's enough annoyances in client-side XSLT processing (including until recently a fiendish JQuery bug in firefox for files generated with client-side XSLT) to make it not worth your time.

I worked hard on this topic during most of 2009, and I just can't see any good reason to do the processing on the client, when it's just as easy to do it on the server.  If you *have* to offer XML, allow the client to specifically request it with a query-string variable or an Accept: header.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is bad and not improving very quickly. Add Chrome to your list. Process the XML server side if you can, SimpleXML in PHP5 and the Xml control in ASP.NET are great places to begin.